# RxJs Observable with infinite scroll OR how to combine Observables

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs, infinite-scroll, observable

I have a `table` which uses infinite scroll to load more results and **append** them, when the user reaches the bottom of the page.

At the moment I have the following code:

```js
var currentPage = 0;
var tableContent = Rx.Observable.empty();

function getHTTPDataPageObservable(pageNumber) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($http(...));
}

function init() {
    reset();
}

function reset() {
    currentPage = 0;
    tableContent = Rx.Observable.empty();
    appendNextPage();
}

function appendNextPage() {
    if(currentPage == 0) {
        tableContent = getHTTPDataPageObservable(++currentPage)
                .map(function(page) { return page.content; });
    } else {
        tableContent = tableContent.combineLatest(
            getHTTPDataPageObservable(++currentPage)
                    .map(function(page) { return page.content; }),
            function(o1, o2) {
                return o1.concat(o2);
            }
        )
    }
}
```

There's one **major** problem:

Everytime `appendNextPage` is called, I get a completely new `Observable` which then triggers all prior HTTP calls again and again.

A minor problem is, that this code is ugly and it looks like it's too much for such a simple use case.

### Questions:

How to solve this problem in a nice way?

Is is possible to combine those `Observables` in a different way, without triggering the whole stack again and again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't include it but I'll assume that you have some way of detecting when the user reaches the bottom of the page. An event that you can use to trigger new loads. For the sake of this answer I'll say that you have defined it somewhere as:

```
const nextPage = fromEvent(page, 'nextpage');
```

What you really want to be doing is trying to map this to a stream of one directional flow rather than sort of using the stream as a mutable object. Thus:

```
const pageStream = nextPage.pipe(
  //Always trigger the first page to load
  startWith(0),

  //Load these pages asynchronously, but keep them in order
  concatMap(
    (_, pageNum) => from($http(...)).pipe(pluck('content')) 
  ),
        
  //One option of how to join the pages together
  scan((pages, p) => ([...pages, p]), [])
)
```

;

If you need reset functionality I would suggest that you also consider wrapping that whole stream to trigger the reset.

```
resetPages.pipe(
  // Used for the "first" reset when the page first loads
  startWith(0),

  //Anytime there is a reset, restart the internal stream.
  switchMapTo( 
    nextPage.pipe(
      startWith(0),
      concatMap(
        (_, pageNum) => from($http(...)).pipe(pluck('content'))
      ),
      scan((pages, p) => ([...pages, p]), [])
  )
).subscribe(x => /*Render page content*/);
```

As you can see, by refactoring to nest the logic into streams we can remove the global state that was floating around before

Comment: The code works great! But now I came across some missing feature: Your code continues making HTTP requests, even if the user hits the last page. Though I guess, there should be some `filter` function before the `concatMap`. Since I can't figure out how to access how to access any data before the `concatMap`, I for now did some dirty code using a global var that is getting set within the 2nd function of the `concatMap`: `(_, page) => { globalVar = page.lastPage; return page.content;})`. But I think there must be some way to achieve this from within the observable stream. I hope you have an idea

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Subject** and separate the problem you are solving into 2 observables. One is for scrolling events , and the other is for retrieving data. For example:

```js
let scrollingSubject = new Rx.Subject();
let dataSubject = new Rx.Subject();

//store the data that has been received back from server to check if a page has been
// received previously
let dataList = [];

scrollingSubject.subscribe(function(page) {
    dataSubject.onNext({
        pageNumber: page,
        pageData: [page + 10] // the data from the server
    });
});

dataSubject.subscribe(function(data) {
    console.log('Received data for page ' + data.pageNumber);
    dataList.push(data);
});

//scroll to page 1
scrollingSubject.onNext(1);
//scroll to page 2
scrollingSubject.onNext(2);
//scroll to page 3
scrollingSubject.onNext(3);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
```